# Nested fragment deep link back stack handling

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, deep-linking, android-nested-fragment

I have below screen hierarchy
[Activity1] -> [fragment1] -> [fragment2] -> [fragment3]

I have a deep-link which should open [Activity1] with [fragment3].
On back press, It should navigate to [fragment2] and further back press to  [fragment1]

How can I achieve this without showing [fragment1] and [fragment2] before [fragment3] as creating [fragment1] and [fragment2] beforehand and adding it to back stack is an expensive job for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Doing it manually

You can detect the back button with `onBackPressed()`, check if there is a fragment already in the stack using `getBackStackEntryCount()`, **and if there is none**, replace `fragment3` using `fragment2` (without adding `fragment3` to the backstack).

Repeat this for `fragment1`. You'll probably want to architecture your navigation in a way that this doesn't look like a hack. Basically, if you are on a non-root fragment on the navigation tree but the back stack is empty, manually replace the fragment.

#### Using a library

If instead of writing the solution yourself you prefer some standard library to handle it for you, then [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) is the official option you might want to check.

As per the documentation:

> The Navigation component supports deep linking and recreates a
>   realistic back stack for you when linking to any destination in your
>   navigation graph.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles

Answer (score 0):

Make nested graphs, where in each nested graph the HOME fragment will be put on the backstack. So of u make multiple nested graphes all their home destinations will be in your backstack when u call the deepest fragment.

[image]

Inside the "deeperlink" nested graph:

[image]

Execute Deeplink Navigation:

```
make_deep_nav_action.setOnClickListener {
     findNavController().createDeepLink().setDestination(R.id.deepLinkFragmentEnd).createPendingIntent().send()
}
```

-> Don't do crazy deep navigations... 1 or 2 on the backstack is probably enough before it gets messy.